# Show github notifications in Mountain Lion Notification Center

Tags: macos, notifications, git

Simply put: Is there a way to show the notifications on github in the notification center of the new Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way at the moment would be to install one of the github growl notifiers, either [githubnotifier](https://github.com/ctshryock/GithubNotifier) or [gitifier](https://github.com/psionides/Gitifier), which forwards github notifications to growl and then use [hiss](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/) (a separate app) to forward growl messages to the Notification Centre.

Comment: Sounds great. As far as I know with the new version of growl we wouldn't even need the Hiss App, as it forwards all notifications to the notification center any way.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try [GitHub client](https://github.com/blog/1287-github-for-mac-notifications) for MacOS.

Comment: How/why does this work? Are you in some way affiliated?

Comment: Alex, I don't see how this needs any further information. Even hovering over the link shows (1287-github-for-mac-notifications) heaps of information just in the URL. it's a GitHub app that has Mac notifications. Did you click the link?

Comment: GitHub MacOS client no longer sends notifications as they deemed that feature unfinished and not good enough. They say to resort to email or web notifications.